# I cant use dynamic with Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

In a class in my PCL project ive defined

protected dynamic model;

Thought it was smart b'cuz model could then be anything to the children that inherit this class. But it will not build, stating:

```
Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
```

Am I missing something, or it cant be done?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `dynamic`? I'd rather avoid using dynamics if your code is completely in .NET/PInvokes. If you want to store an object whichs type is unknown, use `object` instead

Comment: Is there anything you're stuck on atm?

Comment: It depends on versions. According to the [doc page for the class mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dynamicattribute.aspx) it is in the `System.Core.dll` and Version Information says _Supported in: Portable Class Library_. Do you have a reference to `System.Core`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the runtime support for *dynamic*, provided by the Microsoft.CSharp assembly.  It is not available when your library targets one of the "old" frameworks: XBox or Windows Phone 7.x.

Comment: Actually you can target `Silverlight 4`, but you can't target `.NET 4.0` -- It's counter intuitive, but true. `.NET 4.5, Silverlight 4 & 5, WinRT, Win Phone 8` is the broadest profile that supports dynamic.

Comment: Microsoft has a [chart of which features are available with which targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx#features).  I am not sure if it or @jbtule is correct with respect to Windows Phone.